# $p$-norm of Fourier dual of absolute value of a boolean function

Tags: fourier-analysis, inequalities

Consider a boolean function $f: \mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{R}$. Let $\hat f$ denote the Fourier dual of $f$. Let $g: \mathbb{F}_2^n\to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ be defined as $g(x) = |f(x)|$.
Is it true that $||\hat g||_p \ge ||\hat f||_p$ for all real numbers $p\ge 2$?

When $p$ is an even integer, the result follows from duality between convolution and pointwise multiplication. When $p$ is not an integer, I have no idea what to do.

Comment: it might help to define the fourier dual in the question